# In react.js how can you asynchronously assign source attribute for video.js object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js, aws-amplify

My knowledge gap is understanding how to use async properly to have the correct value for attribute 'src' of object 'const videoJsOptions'.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import VideoPlayer from "./VideoPlayer";
import Amplify, { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';

function VideoPlayerPage () {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({ vidSrc: "" })

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getURI() {
        try {
            const value = await Storage.get("andy_2020_something_description.mp4");
                    console.log(value);
            setState({ vidSrc: value });
        } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
          } 
        }
        getURI();
    }, [] );

    const videoJsOptions = {
        autoplay: true,
        controls: true,
        sources: [{
// If I replace the reference to state on the line below with a string of the URL then the video.js player will work fine.
            src: state.vidSrc,
            type: 'video/mp4'
        }]
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1> value of state: { state.vidSrc } </h1>
            <VideoPlayer {...videoJsOptions} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default VideoPlayerPage
```

So what is rendered/displayed on the page by the line:

> ## value of state: { state.vidSrc }

is a perfectly valid URL. If I hardcode this URL as a string to replace the variable on line:

> src: state.vidSrc,
> then the video.js player works fine.

I'm thinking that 'const videoJsOptions' may be passed to the VideoPlayer Component too early, but I cannot figure out how to fix this, that is, have it wait until later such as when the line:

> ## value of state: { state.vidSrc }

is displayed.

Ideas to debug further are greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that the setState is getting called inside the useEffect?

Comment: What src do you receive in your VideoPlayer component?

Comment: ```useEffect(() => {
    videoJsOptions.sources[0].src = state.vidSrc;
  }, [state.vidSrc]);
```

Can you try adding this after videoJsOptions const declaration

Comment: @UdayaPrakash sadly this does not seem to work. Any other ideas are welcome! Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @ArnaudV I've possibly not done this right, so I'll double check later. The VideoPlayer was exactly the same as the example https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-react.html . I've since added:
<body>INSIDE VIDEOplayer -> {this.props.vidSrc} </body>
before the last </div>
Like I said my code could be wrong. this.props.vidSrc does not resolve to anything.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier I believe setState does work because the line <h1> value of state: { state.vidSrc } </h1> produces a valid presigned URL.

Comment: Probably not the best solution, but if anyone knows of an examples of video.js running in react somewhere on the web I'd be keen to see. I may be able to learn by reverse engineering through the dev console.

Comment: why dont you do a conditional rendering,  {  state.vidSrc && <VideoPlayer {...videoJsOptions} /> } this would ensure that the player is only rendered after the correct value is available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont you do a conditional rendering,

```
 { state.vidSrc && <VideoPlayer {...videoJsOptions} /> }
```

this would ensure that the player is only rendered after the correct value is available